# How to start a console program that does not close after execution by TFS Release Agent

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to get the TFS Release Agent to run multiple console applications and then keep them running without blocking the release process.

I'm running a Powershell script where the start process function is used to run the .exe files. However, all programs close shortly after opening when this script is called by the Release Agent. When I start the script manually, all windows remain open and it works the way it should.

The Release Agent is in interactive-mode and runs in the foreground at system startup.

I have tried the -Wait argument, it keeps the application open, but does not finish the agent's task and blocks the release.

I also tried the Start-Job command, but it didn't happen at all and I need the processes in the foreground.

Start-Process -FilePath C:\microservices\Hoster\Singlehost.exe -Verb open -PassThru -argument "DataProvider"

The Processes should all be started in foreground, and keep running after the release is finished.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Hi Mannipulator, have you considered running you exe's as window services on your target machine? you could then then just stop, uninstall, reinstall, start upon deployment.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to solve this was the Windows Task Scheduler.
I schedule a task that only runs once after 60 seconds.

The PowerShell task looks like this:

```
$startDate=[DateTime]::Now.AddSeconds(60)              
schtasks /create /tn "Start Agent" /tr "C:\agent\myagent.exe}/" /sc once /st $startDate.ToString("HH:mm") /sd $startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") /it /f
```

You have to run the service with a local or domain account as a service or interactive.

Here is the documentation for the [schtaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc725744(v=ws.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4028438) command.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the START command to run each exe:

```
START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```